# Packing data to COM (serial port) in python

Tags: python, package, crc

So, I have a custom way for calculating CRC

Here it is :

```
class CrcCalc:
def __init__(self):
    msk_11_4 = 0x0810
    msk_0 = 0x0001
    msk_data = 0x80
    msk_15 = 0x8000
    high = 1
    low = 0

def __getcrc(self, buf):
    msk_11_4 = 0x0810
   # msk_0 = 0x0001
   # msk_data = 0x80
    msk_15 = 0x8000
    crc = 0xffff
    j=0
    k = j
    j += 1
    for k  in buf[k]:
        data = buf[ord(k)]
        i = 0
        while i <= 7:
            data << 1
            crc_15 = crc & msk_15
            if (data & msk_15):
                flag = crc_15
                flag = 0 if crc_15 == msk_15 else msk_15
            else:
                flag = crc_15
            if (flag):
                crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1
            else:
                crc << 1

    return crc
```

I need to send to serial port some data and recieve the answer in bytes.

The data I have to send is : 90 b8 00 00 07 55 a4 7b 00 da 03 02 05 01
the first two bytes are CRC for header, then 5 bytes are header, where last two bytes are CRC of the data and then 7 bytes are data, I need to receive the answer like this ( 39 6d 00 20).

But I can't understand how I must pack my data and send it to serial port to receive something.

Comment: we need a bit more input, what is the `buf` argument expected to be? and do returned packets need to be check through the same crc check? are returned packets of the same format? i would suggest the best option is to write a wrapper for the port so you sould simply call something like `crc_port.send_packet(header, data)` and it works out the crc and sends the data for you transparently. but without knowing the right inputs i cannot help you write this.

Comment: Especially, this code is rewritning of the original C code, which counting crc.
Here it is `unsigned short TForm1::CrcCalc(unsigned char buf[], unsigned char size)
{
  unsigned short flag, crc_15;
  unsigned short crc = 0xFFFF;
 int i,k;
 unsigned char data;

  for(k = 0; k < size; k++)
 {
  data = buf[k];
  for (i = 0; i <= 7; data <<= 1,i++)
  {
   crc_15 = crc & msk_15;
   if (data & msk_data)
    flag = crc_15 == msk_15? 0: msk_15;
   else
    flag  = crc_15;
   if (flag)
    crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1;
   else
    crc <<= 1;
  }
 }
 return crc;
}`

Comment: Yes, returned packets need to be checked throug the same crc check, yes the returned packets are the same format. `buf`  is an array that must be filled in by the algorithm above
`ComPort1->Receive(ReceiveBuf);

  buf[7] = WeigandAddress;
  buf[8] = 0x00;
  buf[9] = 0xDA;
  buf[10] = 0x03;
  buf[11] = 0x02;
  buf[12] = ReaderNum;
  buf[13] = LOW;

  crc = CrcCalc(buf+7, 7);

  buf[5] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
  buf[6] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0x00FF);
  buf[4] = 0x07;
  buf[3] = 0x00;
  buf[2] = CommandCounter;

  crc = CrcCalc(buf+2, 5);`
and then it uses like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, you need to call the function `def__getcrc(self, buf)` to get the return of the program.
Like this (it goes at the very bottom):

```
__getcrc(num-self-here, number-buf-here)
```

I put *num-self-here* and *number-buf-here* because I don't exactly understand what your program does.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It probably dont helped yet, because i cant uderstand how i must use it in data packing to send this into serial port, for example i wrote this 
     ` try:
      ser = serial.Serial('COM3')
    ser.baudrate = 57600
    ser.timeout = 0.1
    ser.open()
  except Exception as e:
    print('Error opening port - ' + str(e))

while ser.isOpen():
    try:
     ser.write(b'\x90,\xB8,\0,\0,\a,\x55,\xA4,\x7B,\0,\xDA,\x03,\x02,\x05,\')
    finally:
        ser.read()
          print(ser.read())`
and i get the answer 
`b' '` so i cant understand what am i doing wrong